# latex UKenglish package error

Tags: latex, tex-live

Today I tried to recompile a `.tex` file which I had compiled with no problem not so long before. And I got an error:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown option `UKenglish'. Either you  misspelled it (babel) or the language definition file UKenglish.ldf was not found.


See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.393 \ProcessOptions*
```

I checked and I do have the file

`/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/ukenglish.ldf`

Moreover I am not even using this package in my document. I am unsure what have happened between the last time I run this file and now, but maybe someone has an idea what I should do?

My operating system is:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X 
ProductVersion: 10.13.4
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
% \usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could try specifyig 'british' instead of 'UKenglish'.

I did notice, though, that I got the same error message as you when I had temporary files (i.e., .aux files) from a previous latex run around. Try removing them.

Comment: Actually I'm not even using this package, I don't need it and including it doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @madasionka Which package? babel? Sure you do, read the error message you posted. You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve